# Executing MongoDB Aggregation Pipelines from a String in Node.js: Converting String to BSONDocument[]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework, bson

Stack Overflow community!

I'm currently working on a Node.js application that interacts with a MongoDB database. My application needs to execute MongoDB aggregation pipelines that are stored in the database as strings. These pipelines are quite complex, including various aggregation stages such as $match, $group, and even $function for custom JavaScript operations.

Here's the workflow I'm dealing with:

The aggregation pipelines are predefined and stored in MongoDB as strings. For example, a pipeline might look like this when retrieved (simplified for clarity):

```
"[{ \"$match\": { \"status\": \"active\" } }, { \"$group\": { \"_id\": \"$category\", \"total\": { \"$sum\": 1 } } }]"
```

My Node.js application retrieves these strings from the database.

I need to execute these pipelines against their respective collections.

The challenge I'm facing is converting these string representations of aggregation pipelines into a format that MongoDB's Node.js driver can execute. I'm aware of potential security implications and am looking for a safe and efficient way to achieve this.

I've looked into manually parsing the string to JSON and handling special MongoDB types (ObjectId, $date, custom JavaScript functions in $function, etc.), but this approach seems cumbersome and error-prone, especially for more complex pipelines.

Is there an established method or best practice for handling this scenario? How can I safely and effectively convert these stored string representations into executable aggregation pipelines in Node.js?

Any advice or pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Should be simply as

```
db.getCollection("collection").aggregate(JSON.parse("[{ \"$match\": { \"status\": \"active\" } }, { \"$group\": { \"_id\": \"$category\", \"total\": { \"$sum\": 1 } } }]"))
```

Yes, "NoSQL-Injections" would be a serious topic. Maybe better store JSON objects in your MongoDB rather than strings.

Comment: Yes I've tried this but I got this error : 
 MongoInvalidArgumentError: Argument "pipeline" must be an array of aggregation stages. I just don't get it

Comment: Try to parse the sting as JSON. Does it work? It's also a disadvantage of storing strings, the syntax is not checked.